# Get href of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have a link inside a div:

```
<div class="embed">
<a href="http://google.com/"></a>
</div>​
```

So now I want to append Facebook comment system:

```
$('.embed a').append('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + this + '" data-num-posts="1" data-width="470"></div>');​
```

As you can see I have 'this' for the href, it doesnt work for me. I would like to have the url of the link Im appending the comment system on. How do I find and implement this url?
Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggRLh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one `'.embed a'`, you need to operate on each of them and give the correct href :

```
$('.embed a').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" data-num-posts="1" data-width="470"></div>');
});​
```

Comment: (However it was exactly what I was looking for...)

Comment: There was a typo (forgot a $). I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

`this is not available in this context` you have to use that element it self `$('.embed a').attr('href')`

```
$('.embed a').append('<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + $('.embed a').attr('href') + '" data-num-posts="1" data-width="470"></div>');​
```

Comment: Hi Adil, I actually have the problem of having dynamic url's. There are may url's which are in a same class(embed) Do you perhaps know how to find this url in the same element? Im thinking something like `$('a', this).attr('href')` But it didnt work....Thanks by the way, I think your anwser is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the href by doing something like this

```
var href=$('.embed a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
$('.embed').find('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `this` just use `$('.embed a').attr('href')`

you can see here: **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggRLh/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html` method, within context of `html` function, `this` refers to your anchor link(s).

```
$('.embed a').html(function(i, c){
    return '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-num-posts="1" data-width="470"></div>'
});
```

If you want to append/prepend the html markup and your element have html content, you can concatenate the html contents:

```
$('.embed a').html(function(i, current){
    return current + '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="' + this.href + '" data-num-posts="1" data-width="470"></div>'
});
```